# List resources like css and javascript files of page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript, css, webpage

In Firefox, (on normal pages) there is "Page info" in the context menu. It lists images on ("embedded"?) the page along with their full URLs. But other "external" files are not listed.

Can I view a list of other resources, all "page requisites" (as wget calls them), like css files and javascript files, with their full URLs?

**EDIT** without parsing the source code with my eyes.

Comment: Appears there is a "list resources" option in FF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157267/32453

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with the [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) add-on. If you activate Firebug, click the **Net** tab and refresh the page it should show requests for the main page and all associated resources. Note that you may sometimes need to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when refreshing to ensure that it doesn't use the cache.

[image]

Comment: Just working on adding the same answer. Good job.

Comment: will this show failed (404, etc.) requests?

Comment: It should do yes. The **Status** column will show '404 Not Found' etc. instead of '200 OK' and it will be highlighted red.

Answer (score 1):

One other option would be to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It's a third party program that logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. There is a Firefox add-on called [FiddlerHook](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/addons/fiddlerhook/) which makes using Fiddler with Firefox easier.

Comment: maybe kind of an overkill here, but this is something I was hoping for for a long time! this way I can monitor what my addons are doing (reporting home, etc.)

Comment: Yes overkill for your original question but just another option.